# Publishing Location-aware Post via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, facebook-php-sdk

It is my understanding that the Post object is now Location-aware.

However, I can't seem to find documentation on how to publish location-aware Posts via the Graph API.

My app is currently publishing Checkins that reference a Place - but I would like to migrate to location-aware Posts since Places are being deprecated.

I understand that Checkins are sticking around, and that they will now reference a Page instead of a Place, but, unless I'm mistaken, the Page ID reference is still mandatory, and I am in need of my location-aware post/checkin having an *optional* Page reference.. hence my desire to move to Posts that have location capabilities.

Please let me know if I am incorrect in any of my assumptions..

I tried finding these questions, but none of them seem to hit exactly on the things I needed to know.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently attach a location to a post via the graph api.  Keep an eye on the [Facebook developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) to see if that changes.

Answer (score 7):

So you can now add location to posts and photos:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/

However I think this location is still added by giving a place ID or page ID (I'm not sure which, actually.)  But I think you're asking if you can add location without a place/page ID?  Personally I would like to do this as well, e.g. use lat/lon coords.

When you post through facebook proper, it can automatically add your general location (e.g. "near [nearest city/municipality]") however I don't see a way to achieve the same thing through the FB API.

Comment: For the record: you need a place ID, not a page ID. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/place_tagging/

Comment: [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/) extended this: _The place parameter can be one of three things: (1) The URL of an Open Graph object from your app that has location information added to it, (2) The URL of an Open Graph object from a third-party app that has location information, (3) The ID of a Facebook Page that is a place_.