# How can I add my own checkin location using graph api in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

How to create my own checkin location while performing checkins?

I want to add "at office" as my checkin place.How to add this to Places api and get Placeid,so that I  can use this placeid to publish a checkin.

I have been searching on this for the past 2 days,but didnt find any solution.

I think there is an app called FourSquare doing this type of Fake checkin.

Is there any API in doing this?

Comment: See this:-https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Comment: Yes I have gone through this,but didnt find any solution for creating fake checkins.please help me.Thanks for reply

Comment: @Ali-please suggest for the solution

Comment: what do you mean by fake check-in?

Comment: how to post check-in :-http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125379/publish-a-facebook-checkin-using-graph-api and you can get places list near to you by providing your current long/lat  in the request.See here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147947/facebook-graph-api-search-places-by-category

Comment: The `Checkin` object is deprecated. You have to use `Post` instead. Please read my post about it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13828245/1515819

Comment: So,How can I add my own location to places api?please reply

Answer (score 0):

Use user_status permission
then get place object where
object containing the Page id, name, and location; location includes the specific latitude and longitude along with information about the postal addresses, if available.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

please check this

if you want to push place information then its not possible for details check here

[Publishing Location-aware Post via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435989/publishing-location-aware-post-via-graph-api)

Comment: I want to create my own location yar,not the existing ones. I want to create my own place like "at office",How to add place and get placeid.Thanks for your reply.please reply

Comment: do you want to create something like it will show you at different  place(like at office or whatever u want)?

Comment: yes,for example there is a location called "mumbai" we will get "was at mumbai" after our name,In the same way I want to add "was at office".For doing this I need to add this "office" to places and get placeid.

Comment: actually what facebook does it just collect inforamtion  from our local device or browser then set location. so you have to set something that u r in that place. here is  a link please check , http://saiberai.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-fake-check-in-on-facebook-places.html , its a firefox extension which will set fake location then facebook will get fake location from browser and will set fake location  another information about it http://blog.securestate.com/hacking-your-location-with-facebook-places/

Comment: I think you know that placeid is needed for publishing checkin using graph api. So,How can we add our place and get placeid by using graph api

Comment: as far as i know : Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating a Post with a location attached. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Comment: Ya,I saw this in developer site.But didnt understand anything. Do you know any apps doing this kind of requirement?My client is saying there are apps doing this,but I didnt find any apps.

Comment: please check i update the answer and also look at here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/ , you have nothing to do about this, all you can do is just make a fake area in your local device/browser then facebook will get that fake place and published

Comment: sorry yar,I cant understand the things

Comment: hey check the 2nd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435989/publishing-location-aware-post-via-graph-api .

Comment: I didnt find any api in that post,for creating my own place.Please suggest if you observed anything.I think you got my question,I need to add just "office"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21518/discussion-between-user1891910-and-mishu-sarker)